# How to remove non-transactional database logging after running integration tests?

Tags: java, spring, logging, transactions, spring-transactions

I'm working on a Java/Spring app that requires audit logs to be written to a database. All services are currently marked as `@Transactional` - so if there is a failure, the changes are rolled back.

But audit logging is the exception to this - it should always succeed - so have been considering marking the AuditLogService as either `Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED` or `Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW`.

The question is how to craft the integration tests. Ideally these should not leave log entries in the database. Would prefer not to have to manually delete this at the end of the test. Is there perhaps a way of marking a test as transactional that would include all transactions including ones that have started via `Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW`?

Comment: Let me guess, everywhere you need to write audit logging you inject the service and call the method? If so,create a dummy service for testing (or use a mock) instead.

Comment: "Integration tests" can mean different things but in this case we aren't doing any mocking or stubbing - guess they are more like system tests in that respect.

Comment: Then you will need to cleanup afterwards I'm afraid...

Comment: Instead of mocking during your tests, you could use an alternative DB, either an in-memory DB like H2 or just a test DB which doesn't need to be cleaned up.

Comment: You could have an application-wide property to control logging, like some static boolean field somewhere which you would set to false when running tests. On a side note, `log4j2` has a database appender which can be configured to work asynchronously (even if you stick to your own logging implementation, I would suggest to do it asynchronously - using a message queue or similar solution).

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions. I found a further problem - the AuditLogService actually relies on some of the reference data which is populated by each integration test. So think I'll have to make sure that data is inserted outside the transaction for the test (and deleted at the end). This is looking messy...

Comment: The above isn't working as expected - have asked a separate question to describe this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31031159

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing exactly what I said I didn't want to do and deleting all the operational data at the end of each test. (This actually worked better as the tests were no longer run in an overarching transaction, which masked some bugs, e.g. relating to Hibernate lazy loading.)